# Αpp Inventor 2 Delete multiple tinydb tags but not all

Tags: mobile-application, app-inventor

i want to delete multiple tags from tiny db but not all!!

[image: img1]

Is there any better way to delete specific tags??

Also i try this but is not working....

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, i find a solution to my problem.

So here my solution: for deleting specific Tinyurl tags
[image]